# Spring Validation

Tags: spring, validation

I am trying to use something of this sort in my Command Object for Spring.

```
    @NotBlank
private String carrier;

@NotBlank(applyIf = "this.carrier EQUALS 'GlobalCrossing'")
    private String port;
```

Please let me know, if this is possible. The field carrier can have many values, If the value is GlobalCrossing then a not blank check should be applied on port field.

Can I do this with spring validation modules or there is another way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 1):

Since your validation is order dependent (*i.e.* carrier must be set before port) you might want to perform your validation post initialization.

In Spring, you can do any of these to create an initialization callback method:

1. Implement the `org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean` interface.
2. Declare an initialization method with the `init-method` attribute (of the bean tag).
3. Declare a default initialization method for your beans with the `default-init-method` attribute (of the beans tag).

However you do it, you can then perform the validation in the initialization callback method.
Here is a link to the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) for initialization callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can annotate also methods you can try this.

```
 import javax.validation.constraints.*;

 .
 .
 .
  @AssertTrue
  private boolean isPortNotBlankIfCarrierEqualsGlobalCrossing() {
        return carrier.compareTo("GlobalCrossing") == 0 ? port.isBank() : true; 
  }
```